# Bootstrap 4: dropdown partially disappears outside of browser edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a simple navbar in Bootstrap 4 with a brand and search form on the right and a profile pic and dropdown menu with login, logout options.
This is what I've got so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--Custom-->
    <script src="../../js/header.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style>

        .nav li {
        margin-top: -15px;
        margin-bottom: -10px;
    }

    .navbar-right li > .dropdown-menu li {
        margin-top: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .nav {
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: -25px;
    }

    a, input {
        color: #337ab7 !important;
    }

    .dropdown-item, a>img {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

</style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1258/1258256.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link">Pretraži korisnike</a>
                </li>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Marko Marković" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Traži</button>
                </form>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded="false">
                        <img class="rounded-circle" src="pic_url"
                            alt="Profile pic" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;">
                    </a>

                    <form action="Login" id="logout-submit" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="logout">
                    </form>

                    <form action="Login" id="profile-submit" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="profile">
                    </form>

                    <form action="Login" id="requests-submit" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="requests">
                    </form>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item">Profil</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item">Zahtjevi</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item">Odjavi se</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

The problem that I have is when i click on the profile picture, the dropdown menu appears, but it is partially hidden behind/outside the browser windows.

[image: Pic of the problem]

How can I fix this problem?